# How do I set all odd rows of a cv::Mat to a scalar value?

Tags: opencv

I would like to set all odd rows of an nxm cv::Mat to a scalar value. There are brute force approaches to this problem, but I would like to know if there is something more elegant.

Extending from this problem, I would like to set all even rows of a different channel to a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

There are no OpenCV built-in functions that do this, but this can be done easily in 3 lines of code.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // The new value for the rows
    uchar some_value = 100;

    // Your matrix (here random initialized)
    Mat1b mat(5, 3, uchar(0));
    randu(mat, 0, 10);

    // Set all even rows to some_value
    for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; r += 2) {
        for (int c = 0; c < mat.cols; ++c) {
            mat(r, c) = some_value;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, this is probably you called *"brute force"*, but this is the method with fewer accesses to the matrix.
It's also very fast, you can eventually implement it with pointers to be even faster (here an example with 3 channels):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Vec3b some_value(100, 101, 102);
    Mat3b mat(5, 3, Vec3b(0,0,0));
    randu(mat, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(10, 10, 10));

    for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; r += 2) {
        Vec3b* ptr = mat.ptr<Vec3b>(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < mat.cols; ++c) {
            ptr[c] = some_value;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also create a mask with odd rows white (255), and even rows black (0), and use `cv::setTo` to set values according to the mask. This however is probably much slower, because you need to *i)* create the mask, and *ii)* access each pixel in the matrix (probably exploiting optimized code, though).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of speed but I guess OP referred to elegance that of MATLAB matrix operations, and sure some of them have been imported to OpenCV, e.g.

```
cv::Mat m(8,15,CV_32FC1,cv::Scalar(0));
for (int i=0;i<m.rows;i+=2)
    m.row(i).setTo( 32 );
```

Likewise, you can construct a `cv::Mat` header for each column separately using `cv::Mat::col(int i)` function.

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of ways of doing this. But you should never be stuck in one language's concepts. Here you're creating a lot of matrix headers, as well as calling a function every time. I'm fairly confident this to be much slower, but yeah, it's another option

Comment: @Miki, if it was setting to zero, I think we both would call a function `memset( m.ptr(i)` for every other row, wouldnt we? `cv::Mat` adds a bit overhead but barely O(1). Stepping through columns this way I wouldn't recommend for large matrixes but yet it makes the  code more readable.

Comment: For columns this would be a very bad idea ;) .. however, I already said that this solution is correct... I just wouldn't use it (personal opinion).. no offence ;)

Comment: @Miki, non taken ;) I just had impression you jump into conclusion about the speed with less overhead than calling a function ;)